# The development server returned response error code :500 when running react-native app

Tags: android, react-native

I've just created a React-native project on Android but got an error when running 'react-native run-android'.

I have tried bunch of different solutions on Stackoverflow but none of them worked. The error screen is here :

[image]

package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "clinoverse",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.9.0",
    "react-native": "0.54.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.8.0",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.9.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Please help!!!

Comment: what is the version of babel-preset-react-native in your package.json file?

Comment: babel-preset-react-native version 0.59.0

Comment: share your package.json.

Answer (score 1):

You could continue troubleshooting or you could just start fresh with expo. Expo makes things much easier.

Ensure nodejs is installed and updated.

npm install expo-cli --global

expo init awesome-project

cd awesome-project

expo start

You can always eject an expo project to a pure react-native project.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is obvious, that the server can't start.
Can you provide the content of App.js and the content of the main page if you have any?

Until then try to delete the node_modules folder, after that open a cmd/terminal in the working folder and run this command:

```
npm install
```